# Crime statistics by city in Ukraine

Tags: data-request, crime, ukraine

I'm searching for a crime statistics by city in Ukraine, especially murder rate. The other crime statistics are also good, though.

I couldn't find it in English, so it would be welcomed if it is in Ukrainian or Russian languages.

Does anyone know if/where I can get it?

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, I'm talking about regional crime statistics only (and I'm gathering materials for more relevant answer). In short, Ukrainian regional prosecutor's offices publish some criminal statistics on their websites.

You could be interested in the so called «Форма №1» (Form #1), which is also known as «Єдиний звіт про кримінальні правопорушення» (Unified report on criminal offences) or «Звіт про зареєстровані кримінальні правопорушення та результати їх досудового розслідування» (Report on registered criminal offences and pre-trial investigations results).

Unfortunately, pages with this report are not located on prosecutor's offices websites uniformly. Usually, these pages are located somewhere in the sections named *Documents* («Документи») or *Statistical information* 
(«Статистична інформація»).

The list of regional prosecutor's offices websites is [available](http://www.gp.gov.ua/regions_www.html) on the Prosecutor General's Office of Ukraine website. Here below I reproduce this list and provide exact links to the pages with *Form #1*.

- [Прокуратура Київської області](http://www.kobl.gp.gov.ua)  ([статистичні дані за 2017 рік](http://kobl.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113579))
- [Прокуратура міста Києва](http://www.kyiv.gp.gov.ua) ([2017 рік](http://www.kyiv.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113469))
- [Прокуратура Автономної Республіки Крим](http://ark.gp.gov.ua/ua/index.html) (no data)
- [Прокуратура Львівської області](http://www.lviv.gp.gov.ua)  ([забезпечення доступу до публічної інформації](http://lviv.gp.gov.ua/ua/lvdoc.html?_m=publications&_t=cat&id=111440))
- [Прокуратура Одеської області](http://www.od.gp.gov.ua) ([2017 рік](http://od.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113427))
- [Прокуратура Вінницької області](http://www.vin.gp.gov.ua) ([статистична інформація за 2017 рік](http://vin.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113411&libid=))
- [Прокуратура Волинської області](http://www.vol.gp.gov.ua) ([2017 рік](http://vol.gp.gov.ua/ua/voldoc.html?_m=publications&_t=cat&id=116634))
- [Прокуратура Дніпропетровської області](http://www.dnipr.gp.gov.ua)  ([статистика](http://dnipr.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=110446))
- [Прокуратура Донецької області](http://www.don.gp.gov.ua) (no data)
- [Прокуратура Житомирської області](http://www.zhit.gp.gov.ua)  ([довідкові матеріали](http://zhit.gp.gov.ua/ua/materials.html?_m=publications&_t=cat&id=116630))
- [Прокуратура Закарпатської області](http://www.zak.gp.gov.ua)  ([статистична інформація за 2017 рік](http://zak.gp.gov.ua/ua/zakdoc.html?_m=publications&_t=cat&id=114396))
- [Прокуратура Запорізької області](http://www.zap.gp.gov.ua) ([статистична інформація за 2017 рік](http://zap.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113387))
- [Прокуратура Івано-Франківської області](http://ifr.gp.gov.ua/ua/index.html)  ([статистична інформація](http://ifr.gp.gov.ua/ua/stat_info.html))
- [Прокуратура Кіровоградської області](http://www.kir.gp.gov.ua) ([статистичны матеріали за 2017 рік](http://kir.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113343))
- [Прокуратура Луганської області](http://www.lug.gp.gov.ua)  ([статистична інформація / 2017](http://lug.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113495))
- [Прокуратура Миколаївської області](http://myk.gp.gov.ua/ua/index.html) ([2017 рік](http://myk.gp.gov.ua/ua/statnik.html?dir_id=113397))
- [Прокуратура Полтавської області](http://www.pol.gp.gov.ua) ([статистична інформація](http://pol.gp.gov.ua/ua/statpol.html), outdated)
- [Прокуратура Рівненської області](http://pro.gov.ua)  ([статистична інформація](http://pro.gov.ua/statistichna-informatsiya.html))
- [Прокуратура Сумської області](http://sumy.gp.gov.ua/)  ([статистика](http://sumy.gp.gov.ua/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46&Itemid=3), PDF only)
- [Прокуратура Тернопільської області](http://www.tern.gp.gov.ua) ([статистична інформація](http://tern.gp.gov.ua/ua/terndoc.html?_m=publications&_t=cat&id=112160))
- [Прокуратура Харківської області](http://www.khar.gp.gov.ua)  ([аналітично-статистична інформація на 2017 рік](http://khar.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113457))
- [Прокуратура Херсонської області](http://kherson.gp.gov.ua/ua/index.html) ([статистична інформація / 2017 рік](http://kherson.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113417))
- [Прокуратура Хмельницької області](http://khmel.gp.gov.ua/ua/index.html) ([документи з питань статистики / 2017](http://khmel.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=113395))
- [Прокуратура Черкаської області](http://www.chk.gp.gov.ua)  ([статистична інформація](http://chk.gp.gov.ua/ua/documents.html?dir_id=111919))
- [Прокуратура Чернівецької області](http://www.chrn.gp.gov.ua) ([статистична інформація](http://chrn.gp.gov.ua/ua/statich?dir_id=113451&_m=fslib&_t=fscontroller&_c=left_panel_ajax))
- [Прокуратура Чернігівської області](http://chrg.gp.gov.ua/ua/index.html) ([статистична інформація](http://chrg.gp.gov.ua/ua/stat_infoc.html))

To prevent you from searching in a wrong direction:

- City prosecutor's offices (except prosecutor's office of Kyiv) do not have websites.
- Regional prosecutor's offices do not publish data on the [Ukrainian Open Data Portal](http://data.gov.ua).
- The source of data is the [Unified Registry of Pre-Trial Investigations](https://erdr.gp.gov.ua/), but access is restricted.

**Update 1**

Regional offices of [State Statistics Service of Ukraine](http://www.ukrstat.gov.ua/) are another possible source.

However only [Main statistical office in Lviv region](http://www.lv.ukrstat.gov.ua/ukr/themes/25/theme_25_1_02.php?code=25&ind_page=stattables) provides such information.

*Some* other regional offices provide such information in printed bulletins. *These bulletins are paid.*
[This](http://www.rv.ukrstat.gov.ua/katalog/2017/08_2017/comp/schor_16.zip) is a table of contents of the bulletin published by [Main statistical office in Rivne region](http://www.rv.ukrstat.gov.ua/) in 2016.
According to the table of contents, the bulletin should contain section named «Кількість виявлених злочинів по містах та районах» (Number of detected crimes in cities and districts) on page 180.

**Update 2**

Elena D. (ex-developer of Ukrainian [Open Budget](https://www.openbudget.in.ua/), probably she knows) answers me: **no**.